how to detect face on real time camera using google_mlkit_face_detection and camera package?
  void faceDetect(CameraImage image) {
    try {
      final WriteBuffer allBytes = WriteBuffer();

      for (Plane plane in image.planes) {
        allBytes.putUint8List(plane.bytes);
      }

      final bytes = allBytes.done().buffer.asUint8List();

      final size = Size(
        image.width.toDouble(),
        image.height.toDouble(),
      );

      const rotation = InputImageRotation.rotation270deg;

      // debugPrint(
      //   'meta_detail_info:- Image width:-${image.width} Image height: ${image.height} Bytes per row: ${image.planes[0].bytesPerRow} Image format: ${image.format.raw} Rotation: $rotation Bytes length: ${bytes.length}',
      // );

      debugPrint('Image width: ${image.width}');
      debugPrint('Image height: ${image.height}');
      debugPrint('Bytes per row: ${image.planes[0].bytesPerRow}');
      debugPrint('Image format: ${image.format.raw}');
      debugPrint('Rotation: $rotation');
      //debugPrint('Bytes length: ${bytes.length}');

      final metaData = InputImageMetadata(
        size: size,
        rotation: rotation,
        format: InputImageFormat.yuv420,
        bytesPerRow: image.planes[0].bytesPerRow,
      );

      final inputImage = InputImage.fromBytes(
        bytes: bytes!,
        metadata: metaData,
      );

      final option = FaceDetectorOptions(
        enableClassification: true,
        enableContours: true,
        enableLandmarks: true,
        enableTracking: true,
      );

      final faceDetector = FaceDetector(options: option);

      faceDetector.processImage(inputImage).then(
        (detectedFace) {
          debugPrint('detected_face:- ${detectedFace.length}');
        },
      );

      final writeBuffer = WriteBuffer();

      for (final plan in image.planes) {
        writeBuffer.putUint8List(plan.bytes);
      }

      //final bytes = writeBuffer.done().buffer.asUint8List();
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('ERROR_MESSAGE:- $e');
    }
  }

I already tried out changing rotation, format still it's not detecting face i also use various package like image still not working or is there any package that detect face i want ML only because i need to change the color of the detected face. i want to detect face using google_mlkit_face_detection and camera package
